# How JSONAssert will treat int 5 and double 5.0 same

Tags: java, json, equals, assert, jsonassert

I have two JSON objects represented as Java `String`s
Expected:

```json
{
"id" : "1234567"
"balance" : "123"
}
```

I converted this into JSON object and trying to validate this with output JSON
Actual:

```json
{
"id" : "1234567"
"balance" : "123.00"
}
```

I am using `JSONAssert.assertequal("incorrect json",actual,expected,false);`

This is failing with expected `123` and got `123.00`.

what to do so that it will treat both the values same.in a nutshell how do I use custom comaparator ,please note that I dont want to exclude/suppress this attribute from my validation

Comment: I would expect these would have to be represented as pure numbers without enclosing "".

Answer (score 0):

The balance field in the Java class should be defined as an int (or float), not a String.

If applicable, it should be defined as a “number” in any JsonSchema, swagger or open-api definition.

The ‘expected’ can be defined as either of the following and the `JSONAssert.assertEquals` will work without a custom comparator - see [Introduction to JSONassert](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert) section 3.4 Logical Camparison:

```
{
"id" : "1234567"
"balance" : 123
}
```

or

```
{  
"id" : "1234567"
"balance" : 123.00
}
```

If you do not have control of the field types then a  comparator for the balance field would look like this:

```
public int compare(String firstBalance, String secondBalance) {
       return
Float.compare(Float.parseFloat(firstBalance), Float.parseFloat(secondBalance));
    }
```